# How to construct the superpixel boundaries on the original image?

Tags: matlab, superpixels

I performed a superpixel segmentation to a specific image. In my hand are the original RGB image and the labeled image contours. How can I draw the superpixels in the image?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is written in the [MATLAB documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/superpixels.html). The relevant part is:

> Read image into the workspace.
>
> ```
> A = imread('kobi.png');
> ```
>
> Calculate superpixels of the image.
>
> ```
> [L,N] = superpixels(A,500);
> ```
>
> Display the superpixel boundaries overlaid on the original image.
>
> ```
> figure
> BW = boundarymask(L);
> imshow(imoverlay(A,BW,'cyan'),'InitialMagnification',67)
> ```